# Notepad plus Color Highlight function implementations

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way for Notepad color highlight and detect a function or property being implemented. for example .new() .add() should yellow. Any thing with between a . and () should be colored. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes is it.

in notepad++
go to : "Settings" -> "Style Configurator..."

Now you can change the colors of your different projects

Answer (score 0):

Yes - syntax highlighting is a combination of a language and a style theme.

The language defines things like operators, comments, keywords etc. and the style theme defines the colour applied to the operators etc.

You can edit an existing style theme by going to:

```
Menu: Settings -> Style Configurator...
```

where you will be able to select the language, then the style (i.e. operators, comments) and set the colour.

You can also create your own language and define a default colour scheme for it using User-Defined Language:

```
Menu: View -> User-Defined Dialogue...
```

The included help should have a section on both of these topics, but you can also see http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/User_Defined_Languages and http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Built-in_Languages#Using_the_Styler_Configurator